# Given these set of points, what would be the mathematical function for this and the Big(O) notation?

Tags: function, math, computer-science, algebra

```
X=2, y=1
X=3, y=3
X=4, y= 6
X=5, y= 10
X=6, y= 15
X=7, y= 21
X=8, y=28
```

I know that f(x) = f(x-1) + (x-1)

But...is that the correct mathematical function? What would Big O notation be?

Comment: Look up Gauss's formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct (or at least, significantly more efficient than recursive) equation would be

```
f(x) = x * (x - 1) / 2
```

Comment: If you're talking about the relationship between x and y, then yes.  At very large values of x, the difference between x and x-1 becomes insignificant.

Comment: How did you determine the non-recursive equation? I only knew how to determine the recursive equation...

Comment: There's a known [formula for the sum of terms of an arithmetic sequence](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATP2/ArithSeq.htm#table151).  I took that, replacing `n` (and `An`, since An = n in this sequence) with `x-1`, and `a1` with 1, then simplified.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Looks like homework. You should mark it with the homework tag.</s>

Did you mean f(x) = f(x-1) + (x-1) ?

To solve for the function:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

To get the complexity:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Comment: It's not homework. I'm making a presentation for my boss about how this algorithm scales, and I didn't take computer science in college so I'm struggling through

Answer (score 0):

Yes the function is right, the difference between y values is incrementally increasing by 1

Edited: Thanks for the comment by trutheality

For complexity of the function you can see y like this

y= 1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3) + ....(1+2+3+..n)

As highest possible degree term 1+2+3...n is O(n^2)
 y=O(n^2)

Comment: I don't think the question was about the complexity of finding the value of the function (that's actually O(1) after you get the non-recursive function), but the complexity of the function itself.

Comment: @trutheality...wouldn't it be O(n^2) ?

Comment: I am sorry, thought in computer science terms purely, i edited the answer

Comment: @Owalla O(1) is time taken to find the value of Yn if we know all the previous values of Y, O(n^2) is complexity of the equation itself in terms on n

Answer (score 0):

The way to correctly state the problem is:

```
f(x) = f(x - 1) + (x - 1)
f(1) = 0
```

You want to solve `f(x)` in terms of `x`.

There are many ways to solve these kinds of recursive formulas.  I like to use Wolfram Alpha, it has an easy interface.

[Wolfram Alpha query "f(x)=f(x-1)+(x-1)"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29=f%28x-1%29%2b%28x-1%29)

That gives you the precise answer, in big-O notation you would say the function `f` is in `O(x^2)`.